# Download file from URL to Safehouse

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript

is there a way in ampscript or javascript to download a file from a WEB-Url and store it to the safehouse ?!?

Answer (score 5):

There is not currently a way to do this action directly.   You would do the following:

1. Automate a process that places a file on your FTP (Ideally this would be encrypted)
2. Create a file transfer activity that is a download type
3. Download the file to the safehouse

During this process the key point would be encrypting it so that you could could achieve the same goal that you were looking to do with other direct scripting methods.

Here is documentation that speaks to Key Management:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_key_management.htm&type=5

This speaks to how using a file transfer activity would look:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_use_a_created_key_with_file_transfer_activities.htm&type=5

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reponse. But my problem is, that the download of the file will be triggered by an user interaction on a Cloud-Page. So the http call will be generated within the Cloudpage and also the download have to be placed in the code if possible ?!?